# Why the solution does not converge in this optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I want to use the "projected Gradient decent algorithm" to solve this optimization problem but I do not know why it does not converge. I appreciate if anybody can help me to find the mistake.

Given $$n, C, r_i, p_i, \quad∀ i={1,2,...,n} $$ I want to solve this optimization problem:
$$maximize \quad f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n {{((x_i-c_i)/r_i)}^{p_i}} $$
$$s.t \quad\quad\quad\quad {x_i≤r_i},\quad {c_i<x_i}, \quad {\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}=C$$
where $$0<p_i≤1 \quad\quad,   \sum_{i=0}^n p_i =1\quad \quad\quad, ∀x_i,r_i∈R,\quad x_i,r_i>0,\quad C>0 $$ 
After logarithmic transformation and Lagrange relaxation the problem is transformed to :
$$minimize \quad -f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=-\sum_{i=1}^n {{p_i}log{((x_i-c_i)/r_i)+\beta {((\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)}-C})} $$
$$s.t \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad {x_i≤r_i},\quad {c_i<x_i},\quad \beta>0$$
Now I use projected gradient algorithm as what follows: 
\begin{equation} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = -\frac{p_i}{x_i-c_i} +\beta  
,\quad\quad\quad\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta} = {(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)-C},\end{equation} Projected gradient algorithm: $$\alpha=0.0001; \quad \epsilon=0.000001;\quad \beta_{(k)}=0.1; $$ $$x_{i(k)}= c_i+(p_i/\beta_{(k)});\quad **//i=1,2,...,n$$
$$repeat $$
$$\beta_{(k+1)}=max(\beta_{(k)}-\alpha{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i(k)})-C),\epsilon)} 
\\x_{i(k+1)}=x_{i(k)}-\alpha(-\frac{p_i}{x_i-c_i} +\beta);\quad **//i=1,2...,n$$ 
$$x_{i(k+1)}=max\{{c_i+ \epsilon, \quad min\{{x_{i(k+1)},r_i}\}\}} \quad **//Projection$$
$$if \quad \quad \mid{x_{i(k+1)}-x_{i(k)}} \mid<\epsilon \quad and \quad  \mid x_{i(k+1)}-x_{i(k)} \mid<\epsilon \quad then \quad stop \quad **//i=1,2,...,n $$
$$else\\ \quad \beta_{(k)}=\beta_{(k+1)}; \quad x_{i(k)}=x_{i(k+1)}; . \quad **//i=1,2,...,n $$

Comment: Are you sure the problem is convex?

Comment: yes I am. It is convex.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is strange that  is also a variable.

Obviously the minimum will happen at =0, and you lose constraint on the sum of .

Although  will stop at =, that is still not right, it means very weak constraint on the sum of .